# pandas groupby multiple columns

Tags: pandas

I have this pandas groupby command.  I am not sure how to split the same groupby to get all the result. If i add another column say "Name", it crashes or take forever to get the result back.  I couldn't figure how to split the groupby.

Please bear with me. I am new to pandas.

```
for x in data_cp.Owner_Type.unique():
 print(data_cp[(data_cp.Owner_Type == x)].groupby(['Owner_Type','Year','Transmission','Fuel_Type','New_Price'])\
 ['Year'].count().sort_values(ascending=False).head(5))



data.head().to_dict() 

{'S.No.': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4},
 'Name': {0: 'Maruti Wagon R LXI CNG',
  1: 'Hyundai Creta 1.6 CRDi SX Option',
  2: 'Honda Jazz V',
  3: 'Maruti Ertiga VDI',
  4: 'Audi A4 New 2.0 TDI Multitronic'},
 'Location': {0: 'Mumbai',
  1: 'Pune',
  2: 'Chennai',
  3: 'Chennai',
  4: 'Coimbatore'},
 'Year': {0: 2010, 1: 2015, 2: 2011, 3: 2012, 4: 2013},
 'Kilometers_Driven': {0: 72000, 1: 41000, 2: 46000, 3: 87000, 4: 40670},
 'Fuel_Type': {0: 'CNG', 1: 'Diesel', 2: 'Petrol', 3: 'Diesel', 4: 'Diesel'},
 'Transmission': {0: 'Manual',
  1: 'Manual',
  2: 'Manual',
  3: 'Manual',
  4: 'Automatic'},
 'Owner_Type': {0: 'First', 1: 'First', 2: 'First', 3: 'First', 4: 'Second'},
 'Mileage': {0: '26.6 km/kg',
  1: '19.67 kmpl',
  2: '18.2 kmpl',
  3: '20.77 kmpl',
  4: '15.2 kmpl'},
 'Engine': {0: '998 CC',
  1: '1582 CC',
  2: '1199 CC',
  3: '1248 CC',
  4: '1968 CC'},
 'Power': {0: '58.16 bhp',
  1: '126.2 bhp',
  2: '88.7 bhp',
  3: '88.76 bhp',
  4: '140.8 bhp'},
 'Seats': {0: 5.0, 1: 5.0, 2: 5.0, 3: 7.0, 4: 5.0},
 'New_Price': {0: 5.51, 1: 16.06, 2: 8.61, 3: 11.27, 4: 53.14},
 'Price': {0: 1.75, 1: 12.5, 2: 4.5, 3: 6.0, 4: 17.74}}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQ7BE.png

It should be group like this for year 2013/ First / Name /Fuel type of car and number of cars sold on that year.

```
197,Honda Amaze S i-Dtech,Kolkata,2013,50000,Diesel,Manual,First,25.8 kmpl,1498 CC,98.6 bhp,5,8.54,3.25
346,Honda Amaze S i-Dtech,Kolkata,2013,57000,Diesel,Manual,First,25.8 kmpl,1498 CC,98.6 bhp,5,8.54,3.45
1662,Honda Amaze S i-Dtech,Delhi,2013,89429,Diesel,Manual,First,25.8 kmpl,1498 CC,98.6 bhp,5,8.54,3.65
1840,Honda Amaze S i-Dtech,Delhi,2013,90000,Diesel,Manual,First,25.8 kmpl,1498 CC,98.6 bhp,5,8.54,3.8
2953,Honda Amaze S i-Dtech,Kolkata,2013,38755,Diesel,Manual,First,25.8 kmpl,1498 CC,98.6 bhp,5,8.54,3.2
3438,Honda Amaze S i-Dtech,Kolkata,2013,39575,Diesel,Manual,First,25.8 kmpl,1498 CC,98.6 bhp,5,8.54,3.25
4740,Honda Amaze S i-Dtech,Bangalore,2013,61510,Diesel,Manual,First,25.8 kmpl,1498 CC,98.6 bhp,5,8.54,4.75
5403,Honda Amaze S i-Dtech,Kolkata,2013,46992,Diesel,Manual,First,25.8 kmpl,1498 CC,98.6 bhp,5,8.54,3.75
6626,Honda Amaze S i-Dtech,Kolkata,2013,51637,Diesel,Manual,First,25.8 kmpl,1498 CC,98.6 bhp,5,8.54,
6692,Honda Amaze S i-Dtech,Chennai,2013,75000,Diesel,Manual,First,25.8 kmpl,1498 CC,98.6 bhp,5,8.54,
7237,Honda Amaze S i-Dtech,Kolkata,2013,38568,Diesel,Manual,First,25.8 kmpl,1498 CC,98.6 bhp,5,8.54,

$grep "Honda Amaze S i-Dtech" used_cars_data.csv |grep First|grep 2013
```

Similarly i want groupby the city as well e.g kolkata or delhi how many cars sold for that year.

Comment: Please add the data sample (as text, not as a picture). E.g. try `df.to_dict()` or `df.head().to_dict()` and post in a block between triple backticks (```). Show both input *and* expected output.

Comment: I have edited the questions with output.

Comment: What is the desired output? Please provide an example.

Comment: It should look like this. If i add more column then jupyter  notebook crashes. https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQ7BE.png

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, use [**`pandas.DataFrame.sort_values`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) instead of doing a groupby:

```
mylist = ['Name', 'Owner_Type','Year','Transmission','Fuel_Type','New_Price']

for x in data_cp.Owner_Type.unique():
    display(data_cp[mylist].loc[df['Owner_Type'] == x].sort_values(by='Year', ascending=False).head(5))
```

###### `>>> output`

[image]

Comment: I needed the count() also to count the number of cars sold for that year.